# Как контролировать нажатие кнопок в AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, видео, обработка

В моём приложении ранее использовался `MPMoviePlayerController`. Это класс хорош тем, что он посылает оповещения при нажатии на кнопки в плеере. Но как известно данный класс устарел и вместо него предлагается использовать `AVPlayerViewController` (вместе с `AVPlayer`). Однако мне нужно каким-то образом узнать нажимал ли пользователь на кнопки в плеере. Не могу найти информацию о таких оповещениях в `AVPlayerViewController`. При этом заменить все элементы пользовательского интерфейса на свои собственные нельзя, так как в приложении должен быть именно плеер Apple. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне узнать о нажатиях пользователем кнопок в `AVPlayerViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы следить за полноэкранным режимом добавьте `observer` Вашему `AVPlayerViewController` и переопределите `observeValue` в классе:

```
    ...
    playerViewController.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "videoBounds", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
    ...
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard keyPath == "videoBounds", let c = change, let rect = c[.newKey] as? NSValue else {
            return
        }
        let playerRect = rect.cgRectValue as CGRect
        if playerRect.size == UIScreen.main.bounds.size {
            print("Player in full screen")
        } else {
            print("Player not in full screen")
        }
    }
```

---

Вам нужен [AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontrollerdelegate) , функция [playerViewController(_:didSelect:in:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontrollerdelegate/1627625-playerviewcontroller)

Comment: Но ведь она доступна только в tvOS, а мне нужно решение для iOS.

Comment: Меня больше интересуют кнопки "Полноэкранный режим" и "Done" ("Выход из полноэкранного режима").

Comment: @RomanPodymov обновил ответ

Comment: хороший ответ, засчитываю!